# Gaussian process smoothers (bs = "gp") in GAMs

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

In his inspiring overview of generalized additive [modeling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q4_t8jXcQgc&t=1515s), Noam Ross makes a passing mention of gaussian process smooths (bs = "gp" in mgcv syntax), noting that they are especially well-suited for modeling variation in time. The description of the gp smooths in the mgcv documentation is rather terse and abstract, and I have yet to find a good discussion of exactly how a gp smooth differs from, say, a thin-plate spline, and why and how the gp smooth should be used for modeling temporal processes in GAMs. Can we have that discussion here?

*Update* 
Gavin Simpson discusses gaussian process smooths and their application to time series modeling at length in this [paper](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fevo.2018.00149/full).

Comment: Thanks for adding the paper link!